# How can copy the matched string into register +?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, match

For the below data:

```
-150000    2023-03-30
421.67     2023-04-20
575        2023-05-20
```

I can substitute the whole line with the first string

```
:%s/\v.{-1,}\s+(.+)/\1
```

Then the content was changed into:

```
-150000
421.67
575
```

I can copy the lines into register `+`  with:

```
:%y+
```

With my method the primitive data was

```
-150000    2023-03-30
421.67     2023-04-20
575        2023-05-20
```

converted into

```
-150000
421.67
575
```

,then copy it and create a recovery with `undo`.

How can copy the matched string into register `+` without changing the previous lines ?

Comment: I'm confused :-/ In your example, what do you want to be copied into the `+`  buffer? All the dates? All the lines with more than one words? The first words of line with more than one word?

Comment: Remark: I suspect that the first parenthesis in the regular expression is mistyped.

Comment: Your current method seems fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first clear the `+` register, because we want to *append*  to the clipboard (`+`) register:

```
let @+=''
```

Now we will use the `setreg()` function to append to the `+` register. Since we only want to work with the matched string, and don't want to actually do some substitution, you can use the `n` flag of the `:s` command.

```
%s/\v.{-1,}\s+(.+)/\=setreg('+',submatch(1),'aV')/ng
```

This runs your `:s` command, retrieves the `submatch(1)` from your pattern and operates on the match, while **not** substituting anything. This internally runs in the sandbox, so not all functions may be safe. But appending to a register should generally be safe.

Comment: Makt it more simple and clear `%s/\v.{-}\s+(.+)/\=setreg('+',submatch(1),'al')/ng`

Comment: I don't see what is there more simple and clear

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to achieve your goal:

```
qaq
:g/^/call setreg('A', expand('<cWORD>'), 'V')
```

- `qaq` starts a recording into register `a` and then immediately stops it, which is a handy way to empty register `a`. See `:help recording`.
- `:[range]g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on every line in `[range]` that matches `<pattern>`. See `:help :g`.
- the `<pattern>`, `^`, is a trick to match "every line",
- the `<command>`, `call setreg('A', expand('<cWORD>'), 'V')`, essentially tells Vim to append the current WORD to register `a` in linewise mode. See `:help setreg()` and `:help WORD`.

For register `+`:

```
:let @+=''
:g/^/call setreg('+', expand('<cWORD>'), 'Va')
```

Comment: `q+q` does not work for register `+`

Comment: Ho crap. Then it's really `:let @+=''`.